# JQuery tool tips not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to create image map tool tips and the image map works fine as in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KGTt2/).

However when i try to implement the following code in wordpress, the page does not load.

Please help:

Code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mytooltip.js"></script>


<div id="wrapper">
   <img width="920" height="450" src="http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/world-map.jpg" alt="World continents">

<div class="pin pin-down" data-xpos="170" data-ypos="100">    
  <h2>North America</h2>      
  <ul>
    <li><b>Area (km�):</b> 24,490,000</li>
    <li><b>Population:</b> 528,720,588</li>

  </ul>
</div>

<div class="pin" data-xpos="270" data-ypos="320">     
  <h2>South America</h2>      
  <ul>
    <li><b>Area (km�):</b> 17,840,000</li>
    <li><b>Population:</b> 382,000,000</li>

  </ul> 
</div>

<div class="pin pin-down" data-xpos="450" data-ypos="110">    
  <h2>Europe</h2>     
  <ul>
    <li><b>Area (km�):</b> 10,180,000</li>
    <li><b>Population:</b> 731,000,000 </li>

  </ul>
</div>

<div class="pin" data-xpos="450" data-ypos="250">     
  <h2>Africa</h2>     
  <ul>
    <li><b>Area (km�):</b> 30,370,000</li>
    <li><b>Population:</b> 1,022,011,000</li>

  </ul> 
</div>

<div class="pin pin-down" data-xpos="650" data-ypos="130">    
  <h2>Asia</h2>   
  <ul>
    <li><b>Area (km�):</b> 43,820,000</li>
    <li><b>Population:</b> 3,879,000,000</li>

  </ul>
</div>

  <div class="pin pin-down" data-xpos="750" data-ypos="310">      
  <h2>Australia</h2>      
  <ul>
    <li><b>Area (km�):</b> 9,008,500</li>
    <li><b>Population:</b> 31,260,000</li>

  </ul> 
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded?

Comment: Yes its loaded..in the console i get the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you've loaded jQuery properly and before your jQuery code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Besides that, maybe there is a conflict between jQuery and Wordpress, try to resolve it by using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // Your code here
});
```